# Select name of the oldest student in the class using EXISTS operator

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am totally lost on this question. The table has student date of birth and i can fit the Exists clause to get the oldest student.

i was able to use MIN(dateofbirth) to get the oldest person but i can figure out in the exists clause

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "can fit" and "can figure out in"? Those don't seem to make sense in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to make sure there isn't a student with an earlier birth date:

```
SELECT s1.student_id, s1.birth_dt
  FROM studenttable s1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM studenttable s2
                     WHERE s2.birth_dt < s1.birth_dt );
```